# How do I sort a multidimensional javascript object?

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, sorting, object

I started to use javascript / jquery a few weeks ago, and I'm already stucked. I have an array / object with this stucture:

```
    {
        "Array1": [
        {
            "data1": "value",
            "data2": "value"
        },
        {
            "data1": "value",
            "data2": "value"
        }
        ],
        "Array2": [
        {
            "data1": "value",
            "data2": "value"
        },
        {
            "data1": "value",
            "data2": "value"
        }
        ]
    }
```

I'd like to sort this array by Array1 and Array2. I've tried  to use  .sort() multiple way but it always says: "the object doesn't support this property or method". Is there any way to do this sorting? Could you write me some examples? Thank you very much.

Comment: You can't sort an object. You can sort arrays, however. Object properties have no intrinsic ordering.

Comment: Here are some tips: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1069666/sorting-javascript-object-by-property-value

Comment: @Pointy You can't sort an object but you can sort the keys and then recreate the object from ssorted key list or you can add keys in a specific order gived by the value sorting. Please see more here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5467129/sort-javascript-object-by-key

Comment: @vasilenicusor yes, but there is no guaranteed ordering of object properties. A JavaScript implementation is free to return object keys in any order it wants, even through repeated calls to `Object.keys()` or in a `for ... in` loop. Relying on property ordering is an extremely bad idea.

Comment: @Pointy During last 8 years i don't get any fail with this tricks. Officially you cannot do this, but unofficially work.

Comment: @vasilenicusor you implement your website code, I'll do mine :) You never know when some genius at Google will find a new Chrome optimsation that causes your code to fail. If it's not in the spec, then relying on the behavior is an obvious (and, really, pointless) risk.

Comment: @Pointy you're right

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although you can't sort an object, you can use a loop, a total, string concatenation, and bracket-style notation to access properties in a desired order. For instance, in your example, if you added a property that indicated how many data points you had, you could use its value to build up a loop:

```
var myArray = {
    "Array1": [
    {
        "data1": "value",
        "data2": "value"
    },
    {
        "data1": "value",
        "data2": "value"
    }
    ],
    "Array2": [
    {
        "data1": "value",
        "data2": "value"
    },
    {
        "data1": "value",
        "data2": "value"
    }
    ],
    arrayCount:2
}

for (n=1; n<=myArray.arrayCount; n++) {
    console.log(myArray["Array" + n]);
}
```

This would result in the same effect as:

```
console.log(myArray["Array1"]);
console.log(myArray["Array2"]);
```

I believe this would be your best bet in accessing data in an object in a specific order.